# Try to understand the RNN module

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

From Eric Yuan's blog http://eric-yuan.me/rnn1/

He gave us a good structure comparing with the standard forward only module.

[image]

So my question is if I have 1000 inputs, then the hidden layers will be 1000 in length (width)?

Thinking about doing a sample in tensorflow that the input is a placeholder with undefined input length, then what the size of the hidden layer is going to be?

Let's say my input with be a web crawler :) to predict the next word.

Comment: What u mean by undefined input length? Num of time steps (t in your diagram) or the input_size (length(x(t-1) in your diagram)?

Comment: Regarding input length, the input could be frames captured for a game play. So the input is like: X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, numPixes]). I could define a state of fixed size, but that wouldn't match the RNN module. Does that means everytime I added a new input, the layer also grow in width?